# HTML - Modal size does not update

Tags: html, modal-dialog

I have built the below modal styling and associated parameters but it fails to cover the entire table in the popup window. What settings should I update to make this work?

[image]

Here, is the HTML section:

```
 <style>
    .modal:before {
      content: "";
      display: none;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      z-index: 10;
    }
    .modal:target:before {
      display: block;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    .modal:target .modal-dialog {
      -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
      -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
      transform: translate(0, 0);
      top: 30%;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    .modal-dialog {
      background: #fefefe;
      border: #333333 solid 1px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin:auto;
      position: fixed;
      vertical-align: middle;
      left: 50%;
      top: -100%;
      z-index: 11;
      width: auto;
      -webkit-transform: translate(0, -500%);
      -ms-transform: translate(0, -500%);
      transform: translate(0, -500%);
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
      -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease-out;
      -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-out;
      transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
    
    }
    
    .modal-body {
      padding: 20px;
      
    }
    
    .modal-header,
    .modal-footer {
      padding: 10px 20px;
    }

   .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
  overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
  font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-0r18{border-color:inherit;font-size:14px;text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-baqh{text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-c3ow{border-color:inherit;text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-62xo{font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-umgj{border-color:inherit;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-6nwz{font-size:14px;text-align:center;vertical-align:top} 
    </style>
```

I have tried updating the modal-dialog -> width: auto; to 2500px or any other number but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the table. Surround the table with a `<div>` that has the following style:

```
display: block;
width: 100%;
overflow-x: auto;
```

This solution works at least with Bootstrap modals and tables, it might help you.

Comment: yeah. that seemed to be the issue! thnx